# Proper term for 2/3-bolt compatible shoes

Tags: terminology

I've just managed to find some shoes that are compatible with both 2-bolt SPDs (that I use) and 3-bolt (I'll be using a setup with Look cleats for a single velodrome session).  But it was really tricky tracking them down. Is there a proper term for these shoes?

Some that didn't work:

- Multi-cleat
- 2/3 bolt (this was how they were listed on some sites, but wasn't searchable on the same sites

I'm asking mainly for reference and in the hopes that an answer will provide a key for the next person in my position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a widely accepted term for multi-compatible shoes. Different manufacturers and retailers will probably each have their own way of referring to them. Not all retailers list that a shoe handles both, or even show a picture of the sole, which is frustrating.

FWIW, in my experience, shoes that handle both 2-bolt and 3-bolt cleats tend to be more at the low end; you won't find a lot of options at the high end, where paper-thin carbon soles and weight minimization militate against putting extra holes and two sets of backplates in.

Comment: With respect to the second paragraph, that's a good thing this time, as I don't want to spend a fortune on sites that will only be worn once with 3-bolt cleats, and rarely with 2-bolts SPDs  as I prefer shoes I can walk in for most things